# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 244,244,3), found shape=(None , 2)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, sequential

> i have to create a deeplearning model to extract the water in the satellite images in some region i have collected the images and i tried to built a model which gives me an error in a single line model.fit i have tried a lot to fix this error by changing my whole code and refining my dataset but i was not able to debug it the whole source code is follows:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv
import warnings
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



    #Useful function
import numpy as np  
def createFileList(myDir, format='.jpg'):
        fileList = []
        print(myDir)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir, topdown=False):
            for name in files:
             if name.endswith(format):
                fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
                fileList.append(fullName)
                return fileList

    # load the original image
myFileList = createFileList('FFOutput')

for file in myFileList: 
        
        print(file)
        img_file = Image.open(file)
        # img_file.show()

        # get original image parameters...
        width, height = img_file.size
        format = img_file.format
        mode = img_file.mode


        # Make image Greyscale
        img_grey = img_file.convert('L')
        #img_grey.save('result.png')
        #img_grey.show()

        # Save Greyscale values
        value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=int).reshape((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))
        value = value.flatten()
        print(value)
       
        with open("newpixels.csv", 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(value)
        
            size = 224*224
            import pandas as pd
            data= pd.read_csv('newpixels.csv', chunksize=1000)
            import numpy as np
            
            arr = np.random.rand(626, 3)
            x = arr[:,1:]
            y = arr[:,0]
        
        
            import pandas as pd
            from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
           
            x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=200)

            x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val  = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=1) # 0.25 x 0.8 = 0.2
            
           
          
            print("x_train",x_train)
            print("y_train",y_train)
            print("x_test" , y_test)
            print("y_test" ,y_test)
            print("y_val" ,y_val)
            print("x_val" ,x_val)
            print("x_train shape",x_train.shape)
            print("x_test shape",x_test.shape)
            print("y_train shape",y_train.shape)
            print("y_test shape",y_test.shape) 
            print("y_val shape",y_val.shape)
            print("x_test shape",x_val.shape)
            import numpy as np # linear algebra
            import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
            from keras.models import Sequential
            from keras.layers import Dense
            from keras.layers import Dropout
            from keras.layers import Flatten
            from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
            from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
            from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
            from keras import backend as K

            model = Sequential()
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
              padding='same', 
              activation='relu', 
              input_shape=(224,224,3), 
              name='conv1_1'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv1_2'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), 
                   strides=(2,2), 
                   name='max_pooling2d_1'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
              padding='same', 
              activation='relu', 
              name='conv2_1'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv2_2'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), 
                 strides=(2,2), 
                 name='max_pooling2d_2'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
              padding='same', 
              activation='relu', 
              input_shape=(224,224,3), 
              name='conv3_1'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv3_2'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv3_3'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), 
                   strides=(2,2), 
                   name='max_pooling2d_3'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
              padding='same', 
              activation='relu', 
              input_shape=(224,224,3), 
              name='conv4_1'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv4_2'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv4_3'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
              padding='same', 
              activation='relu', 
              input_shape=(224,224,3), 
              name='conv5_1'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, 
              kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                  padding='same', 
              activation='relu',
              name='conv5_2'))
            model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, 
             kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                 padding='same', 
             activation='relu',
             name='conv5_3'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), 
                   strides=(2,2), 
                   name='max_pooling2d_4'))
            model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
            model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc_1'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='dropout_1'))
            
              
            model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc_2'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='dropout_4'))
              
            model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax', name='output'))
            model.summary()
            model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
            model.fit(x_train, y_train,
            epochs=20,
            batch_size= 160)
            
            score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
            
            model.summary()
```

Comment: what is your x_train shape, because the model is expecting 224,224,3 dimensions of your input x but you are passing None,2 as an input to your model!

Comment: Or change the input shape in the first Conv2D layer according to your input shape...